# iOS - How Crashlytics handles missing dSYMSs

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I have a question concerning dSYMS and how Crashlytics handles them.

My application contains different targets and the whole project is compiled with `bitcode enabled` because of the `Watchkit App` and `Watchkit App Extension` targets.

I then followed the [Missing dSYMs Documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#bitcode-download) in order to manually upload my missing dSYMs.
It worked, the Required missing dSYMs are now striped on my dashboard.

But I was wondering, how exactly does it work? This version of my application is on the AppStore for 1 month.

Will I get crash reports only from today, the date I uploaded my dSYMs ?
Should I manually upload for every releases?

I don't really understand the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

dSYMs contain the symbols for your app needed to provide fully symbolicated stack traces. When you build locally in Xcode, the dSYMs are on your local machine and so the Fabric [run script build phase](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html) can upload them.

With Bitcode enabled, Apple is recompiling your app on their servers which creates new dSYMs. Since it's happening on their services, Fabric has no way to upload these automatically. Apple does provide the dSYMs through Xcode or iTunesConnect. Since we can't access those dSYMs (we would need your Apple developer credentials and we don't want to have them), you do need to get the dSYMs from Apple and upload them to Fabric for each release through Apple or Testflight. You can also use the [upload-symbols](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script) script to upload them in bulk. The upload-symbols script will also work from CI machines.

When a crash comes into Fabric, we look if we have the dSYM needed to symbolicate the crash. If we don't, we will alert you via the dashboard and your Fabric app settings page. If a crash has a missing dSYM, we will store it for 7 days. If the missing dSYM is not uploaded in this time, then we will drop the crash and not process it. If the missing dSYM is uploaded, then the crash is enqueued to be processed and it can take between a few minutes to a few hours to process and display.

With that said, the best way to handle this is to use the upload-symbols script to get the symbols to us even if there isn't a reported missing dSYM yet, so that we have the symbols when a crash happens. If we have the dSYM when the crash is reported, the crash will be processed within a few seconds (on average).

An alternate approach is to use [fastlane's refresh_dsyms](https://krausefx.com/blog/download-dsym-symbolication-files-from-itunes-connect-for-bitcode-ios-apps) command to get the dSYMs and upload them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it provided everything I was expecting.
Just one thing, do you think I can use the upload-symbols script in Jenkins?
We have an automated continuous integration system to archive and export our builds on iTunesConnect.

Comment: Happy to help and yes it should work on CI. The script will output errors if anything fails, so you'd want to look at the build log for those.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Mike, I will test it out.